# How to cluster Houses on the basis of similarity of features+location?

Tags: r, clustering, similarity

I have a dataset of houses like this:

```
HouseID  Latitude Longitude PriceIndex
  1          1.4     103.120    1.21
  2          1.42    103.112    2.01
```

I want to find houses which are similar to each other both on the basis of their position as well as their price index.[Also would need to Rank in order of similarities, given one house] I tried using hclust package in R  and was able to extract 9 classes. However the groups don't seem to have any interpretable similarities (for example the points are spread all across the city etc). I haven't done clustering based projects before so any help in the right direction will be helpful. Thanks!

Edit: Removing the price index column from the clustering data-set actually clusters spatially. But adding the price shows only price-based clustering

Comment: Did you try doing k-means clustering?

Comment: @Dawny33 :yes, similar results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the ranges of your dimensions and consider scaling if you see a large difference.

I would interpret your described  behaviour due to much larger range if the index that the two other dimensions.
See also the [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6715/is-it-necessary-to-standardize-your-data-before-clustering/6722).

Comment: Yes! Scaling solved the problem. I had scaled the variables individually but not with respect to each other -how stupid. Thanks a lot!